# How to disable html5 canvas image data extraction pop up?

Tags: html5

Can we change it to never for all sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a ticket for this: [#19199](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/19199)

You can follow and participate in discussion of this functionality there.